# Firebase cloud functions emulators always write to a default database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I recently set up the firebase emulators to run my cloud functions locally. After setup, the cloud functions triggered successfully but any write to the real-time database does not reflect in the corresponding local database emulator UI. e.g when I use

```
snapshot.after.ref.parent.child('busy').set(true)
```

So I tried exporting and importing the real-time data and I discovered that all database write from cloud functions was being saved in a default database with name *localhost:4000/?ns=pick2-c468b-default-rtdb* and not the database that is triggering the write event.

Is this the default behaviour of the emulator and how do I go about changing or fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

Writes to `snapshot.after.ref` should go to the database that triggered the Function.

If that is not happening for you, I recommend reporting a bug with a minimal repro on the [repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) (which should include an entire Cloud Function, and not just the line that you think is going wrong.

Comment: Ok I'll do that

Comment: Hey @Sammy. Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have fixed the error thanks