# DataSnapshot.ref in Functions Emulators only points to default database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Let's say I have a node in a secondary realtime database called "test" with a value of "foobar".
I want to set up a function that prevents it from being deleted. More realistically this node would have several child nodes, where the function first checks if it can be deleted or not. However, here we never allow it to be deleted to keep the code as short as possible.
So I add a function that triggers onDelete and just rewrites the value.

In short:

Secondary database has: `{"test":"foobar"}`

onDelete function:

```
exports.testDelete = functions.database
  .instance("secondary")
  .ref("test")
  .onDelete(async (snap, context) => {
    await snap.ref.set(snap.val());
  });
```

When running this with emulators, I would expect that when I delete the node, the node would just reappear in the secondary database, which is what happens when deployed to production. In the emulators, the node reappears, but in the main database instead of the secondary database. The only way I see to fix this is to replace `snap.ref.set(snap.val())` with `admin.app().database("https://{secondarydatabasedomain}.firebasedatabase.app").ref().child("test").set(snap.val())` which looks a little cumbersome just to get emulators to work.

Am I doing something wrong here?

I am using node 14, and firebase CLI version 9.23.0

Comment: It seems to be a reference issue ..is this issue resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not resolved, using latest firebase-tools release version 9.23.1

Comment: Posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

- To specify instance and path :

  You have followed the syntax :

  **Instance named "my-app-db-2": functions.database.instance('my-app-db-2').ref('/foo/bar')**

  You have mentioned the instance name otherwise it will redirect to the default database so the syntax seems correct.
- For triggering the event data follow the syntax as :

  **onDelete(handler: (snapshot: DataSnapshot, context: EventContext) => any): CloudFunction**

  For example you can refer to the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions#specify_the_instance_and_path) :

> ```
> // Listens for new messages added to /messages/:pushId/original and creates an
> // uppercase version of the message to /messages/:pushId/uppercase
> exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
>     .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
>       // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
>       const original = snapshot.val();
>       functions.logger.log('Uppercasing', context.params.pushId, original);
>       const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
>       // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
>       // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
>       // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
>       return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
>     });
> ```

If all above syntax has been followed correctly then I will recommend you to  report a bug with a minimal repro on the [repo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions#specify_the_instance_and_path) along with including the entire cloud function as mentioned by Frank in a similar [scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69867704/15774176).

Comment: Thanks, I did double check the correctness of the syntax. I made it into an issue on the repo under number #3961

Comment: hope above answer helped.